# Encountered "Error: Material-UI: capitalize(string) expects a string argument" when using this.setState in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on an app and I'm trying to save the API response into my state but I keep getting an error at this point. Here's the error below:

```
   Error: Material-UI: capitalize(string) expects a string argument.
```

The similar errors I found online is about Snackbars and I couldn't even get a clue to apply the fix to mine.

The tiring part of this is that, it was working until suddenly (without changing anything in that part of the code) it started giving me this error.

Here's my code below:

```
   fetchData = async (data) => {
      await axios.get("...", { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }})
      .then(res => {
         this.setState({ userData: res.data.user }) //it throws error on this line
      })
   }
```

If I remove the setState function, it did work fine, just that I won't be able to pass my data to the template.

How do I get this fixed?

Comment: Is `res.data.user` a string or an object? How are you passing it to whichever component is using it?

Comment: Can you just ``` console.log("res: ", res.data) ``` and add it in the then function

Comment: @Jayce444 sorry for the late reply, yes it is an object.

Comment: @kyrolosmagdy How do you mean, I don't seem to understand what you're saying...

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran ok and how are you using `this.state.userData`? Show us how you're using that object when rendering the MUI element

Comment: It's just the normal way, after setting the state, then I'll access each properties of the ```userData``` on the template. Then, the error is not from the template but that line where I'm setting state.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
 fetchData =  (data) => {
       axios.get("...", { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }})
      .then(res => {
         console.log("res: ", res.data)
         res.data.user && 
         this.setState({ userData: res.data.user }) 
      })
   }
```

what I'm trying to do here is to avoid hitting the setState if there is no res.data.user, if it exists it will work properly, and I don't actually think you need to use async-await here as you are using a promise passed solution

Comment: Thank you Kyrolos, I later figured out that the error isn't from the line where I'm getting the complaint but from one of my nested component on that page. Thank you.